# how to get the people i follow on mysqli?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, mysqli

So I have a table called `follow_sys` with columns `id` and `follower` and `following`, and I want to display the people I follow but don't follow me back as a pending friend request
I tried self-join but it didn't work

```
$sqlFollowing = "SELECT * from follows_syds t1, follows_syds t2
    where
    t1.follower = ?
    and
    t1.following != ?
    and
    t2.follower != ?
    AND
    t2.following != ?";

$Following       = $conn -> prepare($sqlFollowing);
$Following       -> bind_param('ssss',$metUser,$metUser,$metUser,$metUser);
$Following       -> execute();
$FollowingGET    = $Following -> get_result();
$FollowingRows   = $FollowingGET -> num_rows;
```

ive tried something like this but still the results are not accurate

```
$sqlFollowing      = "SELECT * from follows_syds t1
                                 INNER join follows_syds t2 on
                                 t1.follower = t2.following
                                 where
                                 t2.follower = ?
                                 and
                                 t1.following = ?
                                 group by t2.id";
$Following         = $conn -> prepare($sqlFollowing);
$Following        -> bind_param('ss',$getUser,$getUser);
$Following        -> execute();
$FollowingGET      = $Following -> get_result();
$FollowingRows     = $FollowingGET -> num_rows;

while($b = $FollowingGET -> fetch_assoc()){
$ve = $b['following'];

}
  $sqlowing      = "SELECT * from follows_syds t1
                    INNER join follows_syds t2 on
                    t1.follower = t1.follower
                    where
                    t2.follower = ?
                    and
                    t2.following != ?
                    AND
                    t1.follower != ?
                    and
                    t1.following != ?
                    group by t2.id";
  $owing         = $conn -> prepare($sqlowing);
  $owing        -> bind_param('ssss',$getUser,$ve,$ve,$getUser);
  $owing        -> execute();
  $owingGET      = $owing -> get_result();
  $owingRows     = $owingGET -> num_rows;
  while($a = $owingGET -> fetch_assoc()){
      print_r($a );
      echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: What do the columns `follower` and `following` contain?

Comment: the follower is me and the following contains the other user and sometimes the opposite

Comment: you can use left join and right join

Comment: also for following and follower you can use inner join

Comment: can you show me how ? cause i tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You must create a table by the name of `follower_following`

```
CREATE TABLE `follower_following` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `follower_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `following_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `follower_following`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `follower_following`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Id of the user that is follower must save in column `follower_id` in this table.
and the id of that user that is following must save in column `following_id` in this table. if you want to get follower of any user with id = 1 you must run this query.

```
function get_username($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user where id = $id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    foreace($result as $row){
      return $row['username'];
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM follower_following where following_id = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
foreace($result2 as $row2){
    echo get_username($row2['follower_id']);
}
```

Comment: is this the only way ? is there something else i can do that chooses only the people that i follow but don't follow me ? im sorry im still a beginner at this

Comment: and one more thing i use the user's username not the ID is that bad ?

Comment: no problem you can get the username only user id is important if you have id you can get all data of user

Comment: Okay then i will use the user id too but can you please show a query example of how can i do that ??

Comment: [chat link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173826/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-wustafa)

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: that's what it says

Comment: click on the link. [chat link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173826/discussion-between-abdulahmad-matin-and-wustafa)

Comment: maybe you can't go in chat I write a summary in this place also I edit my answer.

Comment: i only want to get the users that doesn't follow me but i follow them

Comment: I saied in the above answer.

Comment: yes it's true when i change the group by things starts to doublicate how can i fix that /

Comment: but i already have a table with columns Follwer And Following

Comment: you don't have a table you have two table.

Comment: non i have one table contains follower varchar() and following varchar()